# Question about simple dot product proof?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

My professor proposed a simple proof to show that $T ⋅ T' = 0$, where $T$ is a unit vector and $T'$ is the derivative of $T$. He proceeded to solve this by doing the following:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(T ⋅ T) = \frac{d}{dt} (||T||^2) = \frac{d}{dt} (1) = 0 
$$
I understand how this is true, but my question is how $T ⋅ T'$ is equivalent to $\frac{d}{dt}(T ⋅ T)$. Is this some property of dot products? Naturally I would assume it to be $T ⋅ \frac{d}{dt}(T)$. Any clarification would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose he meant to do the following:

$$\left(T\cdot T\right)'=2\,T\cdot T'$$

and now

$$\left(T\cdot T\right)'=\left(\left\|T\right\|^2\right)'=1'=0\implies 2\,T\cdot T'=0$$

Comment: I see that this is true, but I suppose my question is if proving (T⋅T)′ = 0 is the same as proving (T⋅T′) = 0. For example, if I were to look at (x + x') and (x + x)', or rather (2x)' they are not always equivalent. Perhaps this is a bad example since we are working with vectors and a dot product but I hope it illustrates where my confusion is.

Comment: Since $\;(T\cdot T)'=2(T\cdot T')\;$ , as shown, the vanishing of either side causes the vanishing of the other side. Am I missing something trivial here?

Comment: Oh I see now, thank you. No you're not missing anything. I was too focused on the connection between the proof presented and how he began solving it.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is how T ⋅ T' is equivalent to d/dt(T ⋅ T). ... Naturally I would assume it to be T ⋅ d/dt(T).

Yes, and T' is defined as d/dt(T).

(By the way, there's a factor of two missing, but it doesn't really matter here.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suppose my question is really if d/dt(T⋅T) is the same as (T⋅T'), or rather (T⋅ d/dt(T)).

Answer (score 0):

For two vectors $v_1(t)$ and $v_2(t)$ that are function of $t$ the rule for the derivative of the dot product is:
$$
(v_1\cdot v_2)'=v_1\cdot v_2'+v_1'\cdot v_2
$$

so, for $v_1=v_2=v$ we have

$$
(v\cdot v)'=2v\cdot v'
$$
and if $(v\cdot v)=||v||^2=1$ we have:
$$
2v\cdot v'=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad v\cdot v'=0
$$